# Replace multiple columns in data.table using a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am wondering how I can replace the values in multiple columns simultaneously in a data.table.

Something like the following:

```
fake_DT <- data.table(iter = 1:5, A = 0, B = 0, C =0)
vec = c(1,2,3)
fake_DT[iter == 1, c("A", "B", "C") := vec]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert the `vector` to `list` with `as.list` as `data.frame/data.table/tibble` etc are all `list` with columns as elements and having some additional attributes

```
fake_DT[iter == 1, c("A", "B", "C") := as.list(vec)]
```

-ouptut

```
fake_DT
   iter A B C
1:    1 1 2 3
2:    2 0 0 0
3:    3 0 0 0
4:    4 0 0 0
5:    5 0 0 0
```

---

In the `data.table` syntax`, when we use

```
dt[, c('col1', 'col2' ) := .(5, 3)]`
```

the `.(` is a compact way to specify `list(5, 3)`

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe I didn't try this one. Thank you! I will accept this answer after the waiting period has ended.